# Get mean, median and mode of 20 number array in HCS12 language

Tags: assembly, memory, byte, median

I have array of 20 numbers (bytes)..need to calculate the mean, media and mode of these numbers and store them in defined memory location HCS12 language. appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have some specific performance or code-size requirement?  It's easy to find algorithms for those three statistics, so what's stopping you from just implementing them for your microcontroller?

Comment: I am totally new to Assembly language, so its quite difficult to start from scratch. :(

Comment: If you are looking for debugging help, see [mcve].  Otherwise, why not just write something in C and use the compiler output?  Or if this is for a class, ask your instructor for help.  This question is not a good fit for stack overflow; it's too open-ended.  See [ask].